# App is not launching through Appium desktop for iOS real devices

Tags: appium, desktop

Appium desktop - 1.14 beta 1
iOS version 12.3.1
Xcode version 11
Mac OS - 10.14.6

error is coming only with iOS and not with Android real devices

error:

```
Original error : -[XCUIELEMENT resolve] : unrecognised selector sent to instance 0x2819b09e0

Sep 25, 2019 1:09:30 AM io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor$1 lambda$0

INFO: Detected dialect: W3C

org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: -[XCUIElement resolve]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x2819b09e0



(

0 CoreFoundation 0x000000023a1853c0 <redacted> + 256

1 libobjc.A.dylib 0x000000023938ad00 objc_exception_throw + 60

2 CoreFoundation 0x000000023a09d9f8 <redacted> + 0

3 CoreFoundation 0x000000023a18ad54 <redacted> + 1412

4 CoreFoundation 0x000000023a18cb50 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 96

5 WebDriverAgentLib 0x000000010269cccc -[XCUIElement(FBUtilities) fb_snapshotWithAttributes] + 96

6 WebDriverAgentLib 0x00000001026825bc -[XCUIElement(FBIsVisible) fb_isVisible] + 40

7 WebDriverAgentLib 0x00000001026bfa28 +[FBScreen statusBarSizeForApplication:] + 160

8 WebDriverAgentLib 0x00000001026a048c +[FBCustomCommands handleGetScreen:] + 204

9 WebDriverAgentLib 0x00000001026872b4 -[FBRoute_TargetAction mountRequest:intoResponse:] + 220

10 WebDriverAgentLib 0x00000001026762f0 __37-[FBWebServer registerRouteHandlers:]_block_invoke + 504

11 RoutingHTTPServer 0x00000001027e6178 -[RoutingHTTPServer handleRoute:withRequest:response:] + 144

12 RoutingHTTPServer 0x00000001027e6934 __72-[RoutingHTTPServer routeMethod:withPath:parameters:request:connection:]_block_invoke + 44

13 libdispatch.dylib 0x0000000239b94884 <redacted> + 20

14 libdispatch.dylib 0x0000000239ba14e0 <redacted> + 96

15 libdispatch.dylib 0x0000000239b94884 <redacted> + 20

16 libdispatch.dylib 0x0000000239ba073c _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1012

17 CoreFoundation 0x000000023a115024 <redacted> + 16

18 CoreFoundation 0x000000023a10fcd4 <redacted> + 1888

19 CoreFoundation 0x000000023a10f254 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 452

20 Foundation 0x000000023aaef04c <redacted> + 304

21 WebDriverAgentLib 0x0000000102674d90 -[FBWebServer startServing] + 440

22 WebDriverAgentRunner 0x0000000102657bd4 -[UITestingUITests testRunner] + 120

23 CoreFoundation 0x000000023a18cd04 <redacted> + 148

24 CoreFoundation 0x000000023a068ea8 <redacted> + 324

25 XCTest 0x000000010032afdc __24-[XCTestCase invokeTest]_block_invoke_2.218 + 72

26 XCTest 0x000000010039e48c -[XCTMemoryChecker _assertInvalidObjectsDeallocatedAfterScope:] + 76

27 XCTest 0x0000000100335454 -[XCTestCase assertInvalidObjectsDeallocatedAfterScope:] + 116

28 XCTest 0x000000010032af60 __24-[XCTestCase invokeTest]_block_invoke.212 + 204

29 XCTest 0x0000000100383a10 -[XCTestCase(Failures) performFailableBlock:testCaseRun:shouldInterruptTest:] + 72

30 XCTest 0x0000000100383920 -[XCTestCase(Failures) _performTurningExceptionsIntoFailuresInterruptAfterHandling:block:] + 112

31 XCTest 0x000000010032a9c8 __24-[XCTestCase invokeTest]_block_invoke + 1092

32 XCTest 0x000000010038a848 -[XCUITestContext performInScope:] + 136

33 XCTest 0x000000010032a498 -[XCTestCase testContextPerformInScope:] + 188

34 XCTest 0x000000010032a570 -[XCTestCase invokeTest] + 156

35 XCTest 0x000000010032c37c __26-[XCTestCase performTest:]_block_invoke_2 + 48

36 XCTest 0x0000000100383a10 -[XCTestCase(Failures) performFailableBlock:testCaseRun:shouldInterruptTest:] + 72

37 XCTest 0x0000000100383920 -[XCTestCase(Failures) _performTurningExceptionsIntoFailuresInterruptAfterHandling:block:] + 112

38 XCTest 0x000000010032c290 __26-[XCTestCase performTest:]_block_invoke.352 + 112

39 XCTest 0x0000000100396e2c +[XCTContext runInContextForTestCase:block:] + 216

40 XCTest 0x000000010032ba2c -[XCTestCase performTest:] + 676

41 XCTest 0x000000010036ff84 -[XCTest runTest] + 64

42 XCTest 0x00000001003261f4 __27-[XCTestSuite performTest:]_block_invoke + 284

43 XCTest 0x0000000100325a6c -[XCTestSuite _performProtectedSectionForTest:testSection:] + 76

44 XCTest 0x0000000100325d50 -[XCTestSuite performTest:] + 344

45 XCTest 0x000000010036ff84 -[XCTest runTest] + 64

46 XCTest 0x00000001003261f4 __27-[XCTestSuite performTest:]_block_invoke + 284

47 XCTest 0x0000000100325a6c -[XCTestSuite _performProtectedSectionForTest:testSection:] + 76

48 XCTest 0x0000000100325d50 -[XCTestSuite performTest:] + 344

49 XCTest 0x000000010036ff84 -[XCTest runTest] + 64

50 XCTest 0x00000001003261f4 __27-[XCTestSuite performTest:]_block_invoke + 284

51 XCTest 0x0000000100325a6c -[XCTestSuite _performProtectedSectionForTest:testSection:] + 76

52 XCTest 0x0000000100325d50 -[XCTestSuite performTest:] + 344

53 XCTest 0x000000010036ff84 -[XCTest runTest] + 64

54 XCTest 0x00000001003a9338 __44-[XCTTestRunSession runTestsAndReturnError:]_block_invoke + 180

55 XCTest 0x00000001003a9444 __44-[XCTTestRunSession runTestsAndReturnError:]_block_invoke.84 + 116

56 XCTest 0x000000010033fbf8 -[XCTestObservationCenter _observeTestExecutionForBlock:] + 520

57 XCTest 0x00000001003a90ec -[XCTTestRunSession runTestsAndReturnError:] + 624

58 XCTest 0x0000000100309a04 -[XCTestDriver runTestsAndReturnError:] + 444

59 XCTest 0x00000001003931b4 _XCTestMain + 2404

60 WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner 0x00000001002eb8e8 -[_XCTRunnerAppDelegate applicationWillResignActive:] + 0

61 WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner 0x00000001002eb7f0 _XCTRunnerRunTests + 0

62 CoreFoundation 0x000000023a11527c <redacted> + 28

63 CoreFoundation 0x000000023a114b64 <redacted> + 276

64 CoreFoundation 0x000000023a10f964 <redacted> + 1008

65 CoreFoundation 0x000000023a10f254 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 452

66 GraphicsServices 0x000000023c34ed8c GSEventRunModal + 108

67 UIKitCore 0x000000026713f4c0 UIApplicationMain + 216

68 WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner 0x00000001002ebab4 main + 192

69 libdyld.dylib 0x0000000239bcbfd8 <redacted> + 4

)

Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'

System info: host: 'AMAC02X25KWJG5M', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:4be:9746:370f:cac2%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.14.6', java.version: '1.8.0_211'

Driver info: io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver

Capabilities {app: /Users/shivani.rana/eclipse..., autoGrantPermissions: true, automationName: XCUITest, browserName: , databaseEnabled: false, deviceName: iPad, fullReset: false, javascriptEnabled: true, locationContextEnabled: false, locationServicesAuthorized: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, newCommandTimeout: 240000, noReset: true, platform: MAC, platformName: MAC, platformVersion: 12.3.1, takesScreenshot: true, udid: 00008027-0004286236EB002E, webStorageEnabled: false, xcodeOrgId: YZ26CAX5CC, xcodeSigningId: iPhone Developer}

Session ID: 586c3e33-409f-4399-be91-47c8c19da537

at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)

at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)

at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)

at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:187)

at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:122)

at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)

at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)

at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:239)

at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)

at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:46)

at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)

at io.appium.java_client.HasSessionDetails.getSessionDetails(HasSessionDetails.java:39)

at io.appium.java_client.HasSessionDetails.getSessionDetail(HasSessionDetails.java:56)

at io.appium.java_client.HasSessionDetails.getPlatformName(HasSessionDetails.java:65)

at io.appium.java_client.internal.JsonToMobileElementConverter.<init>(JsonToMobileElementConverter.java:49)

at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:89)

at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:94)

at common.mobility.Config.iOSCap(Config.java:154)

at common.mobility.Init.setup(Init.java:71)

at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)

at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)

at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:86)

at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:514)

at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:215)

at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:142)

at org.testng.TestRunner.beforeRun(TestRunner.java:656)

at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:624)

at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:366)

at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:361)

at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:319)

at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:268)

at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)

at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)

at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1244)

at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1169)

at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1064)

at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)

at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)

at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)

ˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆ

Test case execution started: NGM_StoreCockpitComplexPricingDirectOrder_Scenario19

path your day :::::common/mobility/yourday.txt

Reading common/mobility/yourday.txtusing Inputstream ::: java.io.BufferedInputStream@496bc455

Exception while taking screenshot

Click the module: YourDay

Test case execution completed: NGM_StoreCockpitComplexPricingDirectOrder_Scenario19

ˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆ

Test Case execution completed:

common.txt path ::::: common/mobility/common.txt

Reading common/mobility/common.txtusing Inputstream ::: java.io.BufferedInputStream@533bda92

java.lang.NullPointerException

at common.mobility.Common.navigatetoWelcome(Common.java:459)

at common.mobility.Init.teardown(Init.java:117)

at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)

at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)

at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:86)

at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:514)

at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:215)

at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:142)

at org.testng.TestRunner.afterRun(TestRunner.java:1012)

at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:636)

at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:366)

at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:361)

at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:319)

at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:268)

at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)

at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)

at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1244)

at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1169)

at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1064)

at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)

at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)

at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)



===============================================

Suite

Total tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0

===============================================
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: I have applied code formatting to your console output. It was not clear where one thing ended and another thing begins, so if this is the output of several things, please introduce each one.